# How do I model of Y| X, M when data has only X and Y not M, an upper bound on Y?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, hierarchical-bayesian, estimators

Suppose I have a set of Bernoulli random variables $y_j$, corresponding to molecules in an excited or unexcited state.  I have a random variable $Y$ which is the concentration of the molecules in a fixed volume that are in that excited state.  $Y$ has an upper bound of $M$, the maximum concentration, such that $M - Y$ is the number of molecules in an unexcited state.

I have a formula for the proportion $\frac{Y}{M}$ $$\frac{Y}{M} = \frac{wX}{1+wX} = f(wX)$$ where X is a positive valued predictor and w is a parameter.

I am trying to build a model where I can estimate the parameter $w$.  I have a sample of Y and X value pairs.  However, M is unknown.

So I am trying to figure out how to model Y not knowing M.

Right now I just take $M = max(Y_1...Y_n)$, and estimate $Y|M$ using MCMC, assuming $$\frac{Y}{M}|M,w \sim Binomial (f(wX))$$ or $$Y|M,w,\alpha \sim Gamma \left(\alpha, \frac{\alpha}{M*f(wX)}\right)$$ (I like the latter because the data has a bit more variation than is appropriate for the Binomial, though I think it fails to enforce the constraint that $Y \leq M$.)

Either way I don't really know of a smart way of estimating M given a sample $Y_1 ... Y_n$.

I am thinking of reviewing the literature on estimating the Binomial parameter $N$, I found some references and listed them below.  Another approach I thought of was to do something with order statistics, though that my gut is already screaming "dead end".

Has anyone here seen this before or do you have thoughts on this?

1. [DasGupta and Rubin's Review and Proposed Approach](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~dasgupta/publications/binomialn.pdf)
2. [Raferty's Hierarchical Bayes Approach](https://www.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/bka1988.pdf)
3. [Feldman and Fox](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2283836?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 almost.  Y is a concentration.  So $Y * C = \sum_i X_i$, and $ N = M *C $, where $C = 6.022e23 * 4e-18$, 6.022e23 is Avogadro's constant and 4e-18 is the liter volume of the space.

Comment: The formula's are based on a mathematical model of the physical system.  In terms of the physical system, yes, it is true equality.

Comment: Oh wow, I made a mistake.  Let me see if I can edit...

Comment: Okay made the edits.  I changed the notation of the Benoulli variable for a molecule to y.  So $M - Y = C * \sum_i (1 - y_i)$, and $\frac{Y}{M} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i y_i$.  X is actually the concentration of another molecule, but I don't think that is relevant here, I think we can just think of it as an unspecified predictor.

Comment: Your last comment stated $M - Y = C \sum_i (1 - y_i)$ and $\frac{Y}{M} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i y_i$. Defining $\bar{y}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i y_i$ then these are equivalent to  $M - Y = CN(1-\bar{y})$ and $\bar{y}=Y/M$. Substituting the second into the first gives $M(1 - \bar{y}) = CN(1-\bar{y})$, which simplifies to $M-CN = (M-CN)\bar{y}$, i.e. your two statements imply $\bar{y}=1$. Is this really what you wanted to say?

Comment: Stepping back: Can all molecules be excited (i.e. does $M=N$)? It may be that your problem is actually to do with a [Binomial random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), where $Y\sim\mathrm{Binom}(n,p)$, the probability of success $p$ depends on your $wX$ predictor, and the number of trials $n$ is not known. Does that describe your scenario?